# How to capture a screen shot of system tray on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I capture a screen shot in my app, but there are no system tray in the picture, how can capture it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can if you're using the `WriteableBitmap` approach. The system tray *is* captured if you do a manual capture on a device using the Windows hardware key and the power key (or do a capture in the emulator).

Comment: Is there any other way to do that? :-(

Comment: theres no way to invoker the screenshot from inside your code, other than using the WriteableBitmap to capture an object.